# Cloudcontrol push error

Tags: git, cloudcontrol

I have deleted an app on CloudControl, some days later created it again with the same name, and now I have the following error when trying to push the repository:

```
cctrlapp appname/default push

Email   : <email>

Password: 

fatal: '/data/applications/appname/repository.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Command '['/usr/bin/git', 'push', u'ssh://appname@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git', 'master']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

I can create a new app an push without problems, but not this app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved by the kind people at cloudcontrol. Thank you.